# telethon: how to fetchall data from database into telethon markup button.text

Tags: python, mysql, telethon

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="(?i)/start"))
async def select(event):
sender = await event.get_sender()
SENDER = sender.id
idchat = sender.id
fname = sender.first_name

import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
dt = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

sql = "SELECT noplat FROM tblsolar WHERE tanggal=%s AND idchat_supir=%s;"
crsr.execute(sql, (dt, idchat))
res = crsr.fetchall()
for i in res:
    noplat = i[0]

markup = event.client.build_reply_markup([
    [Button.text(noplat, resize=True, single_use=True)]
])

text = ""
text1 = "Hello, <b>" + fname + "</b>" '\n' "please, choose one below" '\n'
await client.send_message(SENDER, text, parse_mode="HTML")
await client.send_message(SENDER, text1, buttons=markup, parse_mode="HTML")
```

i want created automatic buttons base from database
if my data only 5 the button will created only 5
and if the data have 10 the button will created 10 button

noplat = button.text

can someone make it ? any help thank

Comment: Please correctly format the code in your question so that it's easier for the community to help you. Currently it's difficult to understand what is happening.

Comment: See [ask]. Describe your problem before showing code.